# IMPORTING CSV DATAS INTO MODEL - DJANGO

Tags: django, csv, django-models, import, python-import

I'm implementing a list of clients. I want to give to the user the possibility of importing new clients thought a csv file.
The client model has these fields: Client, name, surname, email, phone

So I created this model:

```
class CsvClient(models.Model):
file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csv-cliente')
uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f"File id: {self.id}"
```

and this function in views.py:

```
import csv

def importa_csv_clienti(request):
form = CVSForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form = CVSForm()
    clients = CsvClient.objects.get(activated=False)
    with open(clienti.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if i==0:
                pass
            else:
                row = "".join(row)
                row = row.replace(";", " ")
                row = row.split(" ")

                client = row[0].capitalize()
                name = row[1].capitalize()
                surname = row[2].capitalize()

                value = Cliente.objects.create(
                    cliente=cliente,
                    nome=nome,
                    cognome=cognome,
                    email=riga[3],
                    telefono=riga[4],
                )

                print('oggetto creato:', value.cliente, value.nome, value.cognome, value.email, value.telefono)

        clients.activated = True
        clients.save()

context = {'form': form}
template = 'importa.html'
return render(request, template, context)
```

It works, expect for the fact that if in the csv file I have the row:

Nutella Antonio Dello Iudice

where
nutella is client
Antonio is name
Dello Iodice is surname
and email and phone are blank

basically it interprets it as if
Dello is the surname and Iudice is the email.

How do I tell him not to separate the surname if it composed by 2 or more words?

PS: this a curiosity, but how do I Know if the csv file imported by the user is separated by ; and not , ? Because I set as separator ";", but if the user imports a file that is separated by "," the my code won't work, right?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are replacing ";" by a whitespace. So a row like `Nutella;Antonio Dello; Iudice` would be converted to `Nutella Antonio Dello Iudice`.

After this replacement you do a split for whitespace.

Why not removing `row = row.replace(";", " ")`and just doing `row = row.split(";")` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you want to check what separator is used right?

One simple method would be to check the file for ; - and if the count of them is bigger or equals 4 (0;1;2;3;4) the separator is ;.

For the first question about splitting you surname:

```
row = "".join(row)
row = row.replace(";", " ")
row = row.split(" ")
```

Why do you replace ; with blank spaces? Just split the row by you separator, since in a Valid CSV it is not allowed to use the separator inside the content.

```
row = "".join(row)
row = row.split(";")
```

Now your surname is not split when containing a blankspace.